# Are there any D&D 4e rules or conversions for Iron Kingdoms?

Tags: dnd-4e

I really enjoyed the d20 campaign setting, Iron Kingdoms, by Privateer Press. So, I would really like to continue playing with the new 4th edition rules. However, Privateer Press has decided not to adopt 4th edition.

Has anyone else published 4e rules or conversion for Iron Kingdoms?

Answer (score 5):

There's a conversion project going on here: http://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Iron_Kingdoms_4e